# how to solve mederian art Method StackOverFlow error, method have Base Case

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to make moderian art with recursion. I have written the code but every time it runs it shows StackOverflow error. I checked so many times to find where I am wrong. I also have a base case to stop recursion but still, it is showing error. please help me with this.

this is my code.

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:390)
    at Rectangle.recursionRect(Rectangle.java:138)
    at Rectangle.split_Vertically(Rectangle.java:101)
    at Rectangle.recursionRect(Rectangle.java:149)


/**
     * 
     */
    public int getRandomPoint(Random R)
    {
        return (R.nextInt((MAX_RANGE_POINT - MIN_RANGE_POINT) + 1) + MIN_RANGE_POINT)/100.0;
    }

        /**
     * this method will split rectangle horizentally
     */
    public void split_Horizentally(Graphics g,int start,int end,int width,int height)
    {
        Random R = new Random(); 
        int Height_Split_Point = getRandomPoint(R); // this will get random split point on height
        int left_width = Height_Split_Point * width;
        int right_width = width - left_width;

        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(start,end,left_width,height);        
        g.fillRect(start + left_width,end,right_width,height);
        recursionRect(g,start,end,left_width,height);
        recursionRect(g,start + left_width,end,right_width,height);
    }

    /**
     * this method will split rectangle vertically
     */
    public void split_Vertically(Graphics g,int start,int end,int width,int height)
    {
        Random R = new Random();
        int Width_Split_Point = getRandomPoint(R); // this will get random point on width
        int top_height = Width_Split_Point * height;
        int bottom_height = height - top_height;

        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(start,end,width,top_height);       
        g.fillRect(start,end + top_height,width,bottom_height);   
        recursionRect(g,start,end,width,top_height);
        recursionRect(g,start,end + top_height,width,bottom_height);
    }


    /**
     * this method will draw rectangles recursively

     */
    public void recursionRect(Graphics g,int start,int end,int width,int height)
    {
        Random R = new Random();        
        int Height_Split_Point = R.nextInt((MINIMUM_REGION_LENGTH - ((3/2)*width)) + (int)((3/2)*width));
        int Width_Split_Point = R.nextInt((MINIMUM_REGION_LENGTH - ((3/2)*height)) + (int)((3/2)*height));

        if(width>WIDTH/2 && height>HEIGHT/2)
        {                
            splitBoth(g,start,end,width,height);    
        }
        else if(width>WIDTH/2)
        {
            split_Vertically(g,start,end,width,height);        
             // it shows error ^ here.  
        }
        else if(height>HEIGHT/2)
        {
            split_Horizentally(g,start,end,width,height); 
         // ^ error here               
        }
        else if(Height_Split_Point <width )
    {           
        split_Vertically(g,start,end,width,height);
      // ^ error here.
    }
    else if(Width_Split_Point<height)
    {
        split_Horizentally(g,start,end,width,height);            
    }
    else
    {
        g.fillRect(start,end,width,height);
    }
}
```

Comment: `split_Vertically` calls `recursionRect`, which `split_Vertically`. This seems like a recipe for `StackOverflow`

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: `split_Vertically` *always* calls `recursionRect`, and if `width>WIDTH/2` or `Height_Split_Point <width ` is true, then `recursionRect` will call `splitVertically`

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: You could keep track of the recursion depth and make it exit if it goes too deep.

Comment: but my getRandomPoint() medhod is getting split point within my length  of the width or height. so it self it is base case.

Comment: If you think your base cases are correct then increase the size of your stack.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040125/how-to-increase-stack-size-to-allow-more-recursion